# problems about the attributes of a python class method

Tags: python

```
class test :

    def fn(self, i):
        #test.fn.f = 0     the "compiler" show "not define" errors
        #self.fn.f = 0     the "compiler" show "not define" errors

        return test.fn.f   #ok
        return self.fn.f   #ok

    fn.f = 1

p = test()

print p.fn(1)
```

I am just curious about why i can't change the values of a attribute in "fn" method

In essence, it's...

what differences are between `test.fn.f` and `self.fn.f` ? i am sure it's ok modifing function's attribute-value , but why i can do that in a method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is the following:

`fn.f = 1` gives the function itself an attribute.

But on access with `test.fn` and `self.fn`, you don't get the function itself, but an `instancemethod`. Why? Because on attribute access in a class, the component's `__get__` method is called if there is any. In the case of functions, this is the case.

If you call a function's `__get__` method, you turn it into a bound or unbound instance method which is just a wrapper around the function.

You can cope with that with

```
test.fn.im_func.f = 1
self.fn.im_func.f = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign arbitrary attributes to an `instancemethod`. The assignment works within the class body since it's still a `function` at that point; it doesn't become an `instancemethod` until the class is created at the end of the block.

Comment: i don't get your idea..can you provide some example?